AWS pipeline source stage is successful but changes in the files are not updated
I am learning CI/CD with AWS codedeploy and pipeline. My project is in GitHub. I was able to deploy my project on the first trigger, but when I pushed a new commit to my gh repo main branch, the deployment started and I can see that the source stage pulled the latest commit, but the files in my ec2 instance are not being updated.
I skipped the build stage when creating the pipeline because my project is just a simple php app for practice purpose only.
Can someone tell my why files are in my ec2 are not being updated based on the latest commit?
Thank you.
I already tried creating new pipeline but It still get the same problem.

check the appspec file in github ,
use this doc for reference
https://gbengaoni.com/blog/Deploy-a-PHP-application-on-EC2-with-Github-and-AWS-CodePipeline-fb38cf204cbb

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
